# JFree: Stacked area chart continue painting after last point and before first

Tags: jfreechart, stacked-area-chart

I'd like to get stacked area chart with beginning chart in first point and completing in last point like here: [image]

But picture is out of point's range like here:
[image]

How can I make stacked area starting exactly from the first point and completing exactly in the last point?
(Different manipulations with dateAxis.setLowerMargin(-0.075D) dateAxis.setUpperMargin(-0.075D) are not helping)

```
    JFreeChart stackedAreaChart = ChartFactory.createStackedAreaChart(name, X_AXIS_TITLE, Y_AXIS_TITLE, dataset,
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
    CategoryPlot plot = stackedAreaChart.getCategoryPlot();
    CategoryAxis dateAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
    dateAxis.setLowerMargin(-0.075D);
    dateAxis.setUpperMargin(-0.075D);
    dateAxis.setCategoryMargin(0.0D);
    StackArea renderer = new StackArea();

    dateAxis.setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions.UP_45);
    ...

    plot.setRenderer(renderer);
    renderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(new LabelGenerator());
    renderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);
    ...
    plot.setRenderer(renderer);
    plot.setAxisOffset(new RectangleInsets(5.0, 1.0, 5.0, 1.0));        

    ValueAxis rangeAxis = plot.getRangeAxis();
    NumberAxis axis2 = new NumberAxis(Y_AXIS_TITLE);    
    axis2.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);
    axis2.setLabelFont(rangeAxis.getLabelFont());
    axis2.setTickLabelFont(rangeAxis.getTickLabelFont());
    ...
    plot.setRangeAxis(1, axis2);
    plot.setRangeAxisLocation(1, AxisLocation.TOP_OR_RIGHT);
    plot.mapDatasetToRangeAxes(0, Arrays.asList(0, 1));

    setAxisColor(rangeAxis, axisColor);
         rangeAxis.setTickLabelPaint(ColorUtils.VaadinAWTColor(params.getColorParams().getFontSlideColor()));
    rangeAxis.setLabelPaint(ColorUtils.VaadinAWTColor(params.getColorParams().getFontSlideColor()));
```

Comment: the question is way too general. If you'll not be able to clarify what exactly you want to get, and the code will not be provided - it might be considered to be closed. Please, edit your question in correspondence to the [best practices](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the effect you want by using the default margins on the chart's  `CategoryAxis`, i.e. *don't* change them as the demo does.

```
CategoryAxis categoryaxis = categoryplot.getDomainAxis();
//categoryaxis.setLowerMargin(0.0D);
//categoryaxis.setUpperMargin(0.0D);
//categoryaxis.setCategoryMargin(0.0D);
```

[image: image1]

> I need stacked area to start for the first point—exactly from `C1` in your picture, not earlier, and stop on `C8`, not later.

You may need to adjust the values to get closer to the desired result.

```
categoryaxis.setLowerMargin(-0.075D);
categoryaxis.setUpperMargin(-0.075D);
categoryaxis.setCategoryMargin(0.0D);
```

[image: image2]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but in this case I'll just get gap between Y-axes and start of stacked area. I need stacked area to star for the first point - exactly from C1 in your picture,  not earlier, and stop on C8, not later

Comment: I've elaborated above.

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing were changed after adding:         categoryaxis.setLowerMargin(-0.075D);
categoryaxis.setUpperMargin(-0.075D);
categoryaxis.setCategoryMargin(0.0D);